# How to store rows of chars from the user input to a dynamically allocated jagged 2d char array in C/C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, jagged-arrays

Given that each row of char is terminated by the 'E' character and the final row is terminated by the 'T' character. I am struggling to print out the rows of chars given by the user excluding the terminated characters.

  It is obligatory to use one of the malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), and free() functions.

Sample input and output could be like this:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| A B C E V F E K T | A B C V F K |

My attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h> 

using namespace std;


int main()
{

   char c;
   int rowsize = 0 ,colsize = 0;
   char** chararr; 
   chararr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));



   vector<int> colsizes;

   char chars[20];

   do {

       cin >> c;
       
       
        colsize++;

        for(int i=0; i<colsize;i++) {
            chars[i] = c;
        }
 


       if ( c ==  'E') { 
           

           ++rowsize;
           colsizes.push_back(colsize);


            chararr = (char**)realloc(chararr,rowsize*sizeof(char*));

            for (int i = 0; i < rowsize; ++i){
            *(chararr + i) = (char*)malloc(colsizes[i] * sizeof(char));
    
            for (int j = 0; j < colsizes[i]; ++j) {

              chararr[i][j] = chars[j];
            
             }
        }


           colsize = 0 ;

           continue;       
       }

   }while(c != 'T');

    colsizes.push_back(colsize);


 for (int i = 0; i < rowsize; ++i){
    
        for (int j = 0; j < colsizes[i]; ++j) {

             std::cout << chararr[i][j] << " ";
            
             }

             std::cout << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should choose one language. Plain C solutions will natively use the alloc family, normal C++ solutions should use vectors instead. IHMO, if you have to use `alloc`, you'd better go with C... But the current code is C++ and does not use malloc...

Comment: It's strange that you're obliged to use the _malloc_ family functions since C++ have more appropriate functions `new`/`delete` and `new[]`/`delete[]` which are safer to use (since they are not just allocating memory)

Comment: Are you studying C or C++ in this class? These are different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of the c++ way that you can do,

```
  string line;

  while (getline(cin, line)) {
    stringstream str(line);
    string word;
    while (str >> word) {
      if (word == "E") {
        break;
      }
      cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here another way on CPP, this way you need to enter letter by letter and in the end its print, if you get the whole line at once change the while loop to `std::getline()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char c;
    std::vector<char> vec;
    while(c != 'T')
    {
        std::cin >> c;
        vec.push_back(c);
        
    }
    
    for(auto& c : vec)
    {
        if(c == 'E')
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
        } else 
        {
            std::cout << c << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mix of C++ and C. So I am going to go ahead and assume it is C++. I'll write C++ suggestions followed by C-style implementation remarks.

```
vector<vector<char>> v; 
do {
v.push_back(vector<char>{}); 
do {
   cin >> c; 
   v.push_back(c);
} while(c != 'E' && c != 'T');
} while(c != 'T');

for(std::size_t i = 0; i<v.size(); i++) { for(std::size_t j = 0; j<v[i].size() - 1; j++) {std::cout << v[i][k] << " "} }
```

---

This is an ugly C++ solution that's expected to work. `j<v[i].size() - 1` to skip terminated characters.

Now, malloc and free are mandatory meaning this homework should be written in C-style. Do not use vectors, vectors are part of [C++ not C.](https://www.guru99.com/c-vs-cpp.html) we need to write this in a C style. Since it is your homework, I'll not post the entire solution, however, I'll raise some remarks to help you get there.

### Logic

The first issue in your code is

```
    colsize++;
    for(int i=0; i<colsize;i++) {
        chars[i] = c;
    }
```

This will override the row with the last character read, E in your case for every row. This will become:

```
    chars[colsize] = c;
    colsize++;
```

### Malloc

We have to store your characters in a matrix that we dynamically allocate (we cannot use vectors). Your matrix chararray, is not properly allocated. This will result in a lot of headaches. The below is wrong

```
int rowsize = 0, colsize = 0;
char **chararr;
chararr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

This is how you do it it:

```
scanf("%d %d", &r, &c); 
char** chararr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * r); 
for (i = 0; i < r; i++) 
chararr[i] = malloc(c);
```

### Free

Now your matrix of chars is allocated. Since it was allocated dynamically we need to free it manually. Always remember if you have n malloc in your code, you expect to have n frees. So, there is no memory leak. Freeing a matrix will be in the reverse way it was allocated. Why? We need to free its underlying pointers for every row the way we allocated them.

```
for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        free(chararr[i]);
         
free(chararr);
```

Comment: what is r and c in your code? I assume it means it row and col size. I do not want to scan these numbers from user. The program should only scan chars and manually calculate col size for each row.

Comment: Then you have to realloc the more you grow, which makes it a different problem.